# Вывод ресурсов кроме текущего modx revo

Tags: html, cms, modx, revo

Подскажите пожалуйста как вывести ресурсы на странице кроме первого выведенного авто

1. Последнее добавленное авто(первое выведенное авто)

   ```
     [[!getResources?
     &parents=`10`
     &showHidden=`1`
     &tpl=`lostAuto`
     &depth=`0`
     &includeContent=`1`
     &includeTVs=`1`
     &processTVs=`1`
     &tvPrefix=``
     &hideContainers=`1`
     &sortby=`{"publishedon":"DESC"}`
     &limit=`1`
     ]]
   ```
2. вывод остальных авто(все остальные выведенные авто)

   ```
         [[!getPage?
         &elementClass=`modSnippet`
         &element=`getResources`
         &showHidden=`1`
         &tpl=`AutoSaleTpl`
         &includeContent=`1`
         &includeTVs=`1`
         &processTVs=`1`
         &tvPrefix=``
         &parents=`10`
         &hideContainers=`1`
         &sortby=`{"publishedon":DESC"}`
         &offset=`1`
         &limit=`10`
         &pageLimit=`10`
         &pageNavVar=`page.nav`
         ]]
   ```

&offset=`1` не срабатывает, все ровно выводит последнюю добавленную запись

Answer (score 1):

Используйте параметр `offset` - пропустить заданное кол-во записей, т.е. в вашем случае без первой записи: `offset  = 1`

Comment: не отрабатывает, все ровно выводит